# How to save a picture in a specific folder just for my app (correctly)?

Tags: android, storage

The problem is that my app saves the picture twice; one in the camera folder and the other in the folder I specified. but when I tested the app on another device, that didn't happen!

```
//lunch the camera and make a file to save the image in and pass it with the camera intent
    public void lunchCamera() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.ziad.sayit",
                        photoFile);

                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "SayIt_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return imageFile;
    }
```

So, I want a solution for this, and I also want to save the picture in a folder for my app **inside** the **Pictures Directory**.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution for it, other than to not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` delegates picture-taking to an arbitrary third-party camera app. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of these pre-installed on devices. There are hundreds more available for download from the Play Store and elsewhere. What they do in response to that `Intent` action is up to them. *Ideally*, they would only store the image in the location specified by `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. However, there is no requirement that they behave that way. Some camera apps will store the image twice, once in its normal location and once in the `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Some will ignore `EXTRA_OUTPUT` entirely.

If this concerns you, do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Use a library — CameraX, Fotoappart, CameraKit-Android, etc. — to take the photos within your own app.

Comment: Alright then, can I refactor the code to make the camera app save the photo only in the default directory? Like how can I make the picture go to the Camera folder so it is only saved once?

Comment: @ZiadH.: "can I refactor the code to make the camera app save the photo only in the default directory?" -- I doubt it. You would need to talk to the developers of this specific camera app and figure out with them if there is a way to create an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` that gets past their bug. And you would need to do that for [all the other bugs in the other camera apps](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Call below method from OnActivityResult.

```java
private void saveImage(Bitmap  image, String fileName) {

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");
    if (!direct.exists()) {
        File directory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
        directory.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do I get the Bitmap and the String fileName if the picture haven't been taken yet?