# My app asks for permissions repeatedly, although user granted it

Tags: android, permissions

Every time I click on the camera button, the app asks for permissions although it is granted; I double checked the settings and yes my app have the permission to use storage. However that problem only happens when testing the app on Dad's phone, so it doesn't occur on my phone!!

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
//                           _______<<onRequestPermissionsResult()>>_______
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) { //ToDo - Dad
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            lunchCamera();
        }
    }

    //---------------------------------        Request Permission         --------------------------
    public  void requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            lunchCamera();
        }
    }
```

**requestPermission on click:**

```
//check if there's a hardware on the device, then lunch the camera app on click
        if (hasCamera()) {
            //---
            snapFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            });
            //---

        } else {
            snapFab.setEnabled(false);

            Toast.makeText(this, "You don't have a hardware to handle camera events", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

**hasCamera() method:**

```
//does the phone have a hardware to handle camera events
    public boolean hasCamera() {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }
```

Comment: what's the permission it asks for every time? Do you have permission to use the camera, because it's not included in the code above...

Comment: You have to check if you have a permission. See official guide https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: "what's the permission it asks for every time?" Storage., "Do you have permission to use the camera" No, the app uses the default camera app of the device.
Everything runs correctly on my phone but then that happens when I tested on another mobile

Comment: Where are you calling the requestPermission() from and also what's in your lunchCamera() method? Any chance you create a conditional loop that triggers only under specific circumstances? Finally, are both devices trying to launch the same app that uses the camera or do they have different default apps? Maybe the loop is created from the other app that tries to launch and performs a failed check.

Comment: I am calling requestPermission() from MainActivity in a method that runs every time the user clicks the camera button but if permission is granted, it shouldn't ask for it. No, both devices have different camera apps; the one that the problem occurs in, is the one that uses Google Camera. You can check lunchCamera() here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660896/how-to-save-a-picture-in-a-specific-folder-just-for-my-app-correctly/57660942?noredirect=1#comment101792340_57660942

Comment: could you please also add the relevant code from your mainActivity where you ask for the permissions in the first place?

Comment: SURE! I edited the post..

Comment: every time you check if the device has a camera you're setting a new listener. I suggest you set the listener outside the check in your Main Activity, and inside your onClick check if the device has a camera. If yes then request permission and launch camera, otherwise show Toast

Comment: I tried that but still, and then I tried deleting hasCamera() method to test it but nothing changed. The problem is that the app doesn't get somehow that the permission is actually granted, but why!!!